# What mass fraction of a main sequence star produces energy?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, fusion

Only some fraction of the total mass of a main sequence star produces energy in the star's centre through the pp-chains, or in heavy stars, the CNO-cycle. My question is about the mass fraction where the greatest part of the total energy production takes place, say 90% of the total energy production. Presumably, this mass fraction is different for stars of 0.1 or 1 or 2 or 5 or 20 $M_\odot$.

After reading [this StackExchange text](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310972/how-do-you-find-the-mass-involved-in-fusion-reactions-in-the-center-of-a-star/310976#310976) I still cannot answer my question:

What relation follows from star models for the massa fraction where about 90% of the total energy production takes place, as a function of the total star mass?

Comment: Astronomy SE could also be good. But many folks are on both so no need to move.

Comment: For the Sun, the solar core (where energy production takes place) occupies $0.8 \%$ of the Sun's volume, but contains $34 \%$ of the Sun's mass - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core.